# JTable with JCombobox editor: handle mouse clicks

Tags: java, swing, combobox, jtable, tablecelleditor

I have a JTable with JCombobox editor for a certain column.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;

public class TablePanel extends JPanel {

    public TablePanel() {
        JTable table = new JTable(new MyTableModel());
        setComboboxColumn(table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1));
        add(new JScrollPane(table));
    }

    public void setComboboxColumn(TableColumn cbColumn) {
        JComboBox<String> comboBox = new JComboBox<>();
        comboBox.addItem("Item 1");
        comboBox.addItem("Item 2");
        comboBox.addItem("Item 3");
        cbColumn.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(comboBox));
    }

    private static class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

        private String[] columnNames = {"Normal cell", "Combobox cell"};
        private Object[][] data = {
                {"Cell 1", "Item 2"},
                {"Cell 2", "Item 1"},
                {"Cell 3", "Item 1"},
                {"Cell 4", "Item 3"},
        };

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return columnNames.length;
        }
        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return data.length;
        }
        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int col) {
            return columnNames[col];
        }
        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
            return data[row][col];
        }
        @Override
        public Class getColumnClass(int c) {
            return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();
        }
        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            data[rowIndex][columnIndex] = aValue;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("TablePanel");
                frame.getContentPane().add(new TablePanel());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

What happens now:

- When I click for the first time on a cell of that column the combobox popup shows up immediately.
- If I click other cells of the same column, the combobox shows up but the popup remains closed.
- If I click on other cells and then back again on a cell of that column, the combobox popup shows up again immediately.

What I would like:

- First click on the cell of that column: the combobox shows up, but the popup list remains closed.
- Second click again on the same cell: the popup list shows up.

I know that I can use `cellEditor.setClickCountToStart(2)` but in this case the second click must be performed in a short time after the first one, and I would like to avoid this limit.

Comment: 1. 1st. is about focus, I'm thing, sure that lots of time here about, 2. last property is to start editor programatically, 3.without an SSCCE / MCVE hard to answer this question

Comment: I updated the question with a SSCCE / MCVE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `BasicComboPopup.Handler#mousePressed(...)`:

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
  if (e.getSource() == list) {
    return;
  }
  if (!SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e) || !comboBox.isEnabled())
    return;
  //...
  togglePopup();
}
```

You might be able to use a `AncestorListener`:

- When first click on the cell of that column, `combobox.isEnabled()==false`, so do not display popup, and later, `AncestorListener#ancestorAdded()` call `combobox.setEnabled(true)`.
- Second click again on the same cell: `combobox.isEnabled()==true`, the popup shows up.
- If click on other cells: `AncestorListener#ancestorRemoved()` call `combobox.setEnabled(false)`.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class ComboBoxCellEditorTogglePopupTest {
  private JComboBox<String> makeComboBox() {
    JComboBox<String> combobox = new JComboBox<>();
    combobox.addItem("Item 1");
    combobox.addItem("Item 2");
    combobox.addItem("Item 3");
    return combobox;
  }
  public JComponent makeUI() {
    String[] columnNames = {"Default", "setEnabled", "String"};
    Object[][] data = {
      {"Item 1", "Item 1", "aaa"}, {"Item 2", "Item 3", "bbb"}
    };
    JTable table = new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames));
    table.setRowHeight(20);

    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellEditor(
        new DefaultCellEditor(makeComboBox()));

    final JComboBox<String> combobox = makeComboBox();
    combobox.setEnabled(false);
    combobox.addAncestorListener(new AncestorListener() {
      @Override public void ancestorAdded(AncestorEvent e) {
        System.out.println("ancestorAdded");
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
          @Override public void run() {
            combobox.setEnabled(true);
          }
        });
      }
      @Override public void ancestorRemoved(AncestorEvent e) {
        System.out.println("ancestorRemoved");
        combobox.setEnabled(false);
      }
      @Override public void ancestorMoved(AncestorEvent e) {}
    });
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellEditor(
        new DefaultCellEditor(combobox));

    JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    p.add(new JScrollPane(table));
    return p;
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override public void run() {
        createAndShowGUI();
      }
    });
  }
  public static void createAndShowGUI() {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.getContentPane().add(new ComboBoxCellEditorTogglePopupTest().makeUI());
    f.setSize(320, 240);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```